# How can I add information from my where clause to my test failure in Spock?

Tags: unit-testing, groovy, spock

If I have the following spock test:

```
    def "A should be smaller than B"() {
        expect: "A is smaller than B"
        A < B

        where: "A and B take on the following values"
        A|B|Path
        5|6|/home
        6|7|/home
        7|5|/home/user
```

I expect the third where case to fail because 7 is not less than 5.  The test failure in the html report is informative enough to show what the values of A and B are but I also want to know what the path was when looking at the report.  How can I get the test report to include information about the path when this test fails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
@Unroll
def "#A should be smaller than #B with #Path"() {
    expect: "A is smaller than B"
    A < B

    where: "A and B take on the following values"
    A|B|Path
    5|6|/home
    6|7|/home
    7|5|/home/user
}
```

Comment: Thank you!  Simple solution I was unaware of.  Exactly what I was looking for

Comment: is this possible outside the where clause too?  I using a variable in expect with no where and it doesn't work.

Comment: No, unroll just has access to your data-driven values (in the where)

Comment: Any other annotations that have access to other clauses?

Comment: forgot to tag you ^

Comment: @MikeSallese not any I can think of